# python tornado get request url

Tags: python, url, get, tornado

Here is my code:

```
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write(self.request.url)

def main():
    settings = {"template_path": "html","static_path": "static"}
    tornado.options.parse_command_line()
    application = tornado.web.Application([
       (r"/story/page1", MainHandler),
        ],**settings)
```

I want to get the string  "/story/page1".  how ?

Comment: can you be more precise ? what do you get for now ?

Answer (score 27):

You can get current url inside [`RequestHandler`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html) using `self.request.uri`:

```
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write(self.request.uri)
```

Comment: If you want the full URL then: self.request.protocol + "://" + self.request.host + self.request.uri

Comment: For the full URL, tornado provides self.request.full_url() in RequestHandlers.

Comment: @F.Santiago How does that compare to `self.request.path` ?

Answer (score 5):

I think what you're looking for is `self.request.path`. Look at the functions available for [`HTTPServerRequest`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httputil.html#tornado.httputil.HTTPServerRequest).

```
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write(self.request.path)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use **`self.request.full_url()`** if you want to access the whole URL of the request (protocol + subdomain + domain + path + query). It will return, for example: `https://myserver.com/profiles?id=115`.

Use **`self.request.uri`** if you want to access URI (path + query). It will give, for example: `/profiles?id=115`.

Use **`self.request.path`** if you want to access just the path without query string. It will give, for example: `/profiles`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no method that gives you access to the full URL, but you can construct it using the protocol, host and uri, e.g.

```
url = '{}://{}{}'.format(self.request.protocol,self.request.host,self.request.uri)
```